# Creating multiple jar files using single Ant build script

Tags: ant, build.xml

I have a requirement where I need to build multiple jar files from each of the project that exists in my workspace. Can you please let me know how do I write a single build.xml to create multiple jar files ? I have tried similar code and know its possible but would like to know what are the best practices that needs to be followed. In my case, there are 5 projects in my workspace and I would have to create 5 different jars. Also there are external dependency jars, that needs to be included in some projects to build the jar file. Below is the sample code that I have written to create two jar files. The  code that I have written to generate the jar file is below

```
 <target name="compile" depends="compileVal, compileHib " description="compile the source for all">

</target>

<!-- ============================================= 
      target: compile the source for Valueobjects              
     ============================================= -->
<target name="compileVal" depends="clean" description="description">
    <echo message="Creating directory '${target}' if not present "></echo>
        <mkdir dir="${target}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${Classfiles}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${JarLocation}"/>
        <javac srcdir="../ValueObjects/src" destdir="${Classfiles}" />
</target>

    <!-- ================================= 
      target: compile              
     ================================= -->
    <target name="compileHib" depends="clean" description="description">
    <echo message="Creating directory '${target}' if not present "></echo>
        <mkdir dir="${target}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${Classfiles}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${JarLocation}"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="${Classfiles}" >
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${libloc}/hibernate3.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="${libloc}/hsqldb.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="${libloc}/jta.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="${libloc}/ojdbc5.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="${libloc}/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="${libloc}/postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
     </target>

<!-- ================================= 
      target: name              
     ================================= -->
    <target name="copy-non-java-files" depends="" description="description">
        <copy todir="${Classfiles}" includeemptydirs="false">
                <fileset dir="src" excludes="**/*.java" />
        </copy>
    </target>

    <!-- ================================= 
      target: compress              
     ================================= -->
    <target name="build_jar" depends="buildValobj, buildHib" description="description">

    </target>

    <!-- ================================= 
      target: buildValobject jar             
     ================================= -->
<target name="buildValobj" depends="compileVal" description="creates the valueObject jar">
    <echo message="Creating the jar to Folder '${JarDest}'"> </echo>
        <jar destfile="${JarDest}/${RetValObName}" basedir="${Classfiles}" />
</target>

<!-- ================================= 
      target: buildHibjar               
     ================================= -->
<target name="buildHib" depends="compileHib, copy-non-java-files" description="description">
    <echo message="Creating the jar to Folder '${JarDest}'"> </echo>
        <jar destfile="${JarDest}/${RetHibName}" basedir="${Classfiles}" />
</target>



    <!-- ================================= 
      target: clean              
     ================================= -->

    <target name="clean">
        <echo message="Cleaning '${target}' folder"></echo>
        <delete includeemptydirs="true">
            <fileset dir="${target}" includes="**/*"/>
        </delete>
    </target>
```

In the above code, the issue im facing is while trying to compileHib though I have specified the depends="clean". The clean does not happen. A jar is created that includes, both the files that were already existing as well as the new files that were moved.Not sure why? Though I have specified clean, the clean action does not seem to happen. Can you please let me know what im missing in the above.

Please Assist. THanks in Advance

Comment: Learn how to build one jar file. Repeat the same technique 5 times to build 5 jar files. But the best practice is that each project should have its own build.

Comment: You have 5 projects. Create ant build.xml for each project, and then create a build.xml for your workspace. Use '<subant>' or just '<ant>' to call the 5 projects' build file. Or use Maven.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I have updated my query with the code that I have written. Also Im facing an issue i.e the clean action does not seem to happen the second time. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Ant optimizes so that targets (e.g. clean) are only run once even through several targets depends on it. Reading your questions and code I recommend that you read more of the Ant manual. From a developers perspective ant might seem a bit backward but there are good reasons for it.